# snmpget does not work from a remote server but works when called from the local server itself

Tags: 20.04, snmp

I'm trying to do a snmpget from remote but it only works from the serveur itself :

```bash
server $ ipAddress=$(ip -4 -o a show dev enp1s0f0 | awk -F ' *|/' '{print$4;exit}')
server $ snmpget -v3 -u svc_snmp_v3 -l authNoPriv -a SHA-512 -A $MDP_SNMP_V3 $ipAddress sysName.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: server
remote $ ipAddress=x.y.z.t # The IP address of my server
remote $ snmpget -v3 -u svc_snmp_v3 -l authNoPriv -a SHA-512 -A $MDP_SNMP_V3 $ipAddress sysName.0
sysName.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysName)
remote $ echo $?
1
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Use `journalctl`, especially the `--since=` and `--until` options to look at the system logs (read `man journalctl`). In my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username) I have some `journalctl` hints, including a way to format dates for `--since=` and --until=`.

Comment: please post contents of snmp.conf file, probably at /etc/snmp/snmp.conf

Comment: @jtessier72 Thanks. I used a solution from https://thejoyofstick.com/blog/2019/05/28/installing-snmp-mib-files-in-linux-ubuntu-12-04-lts/. I commented the line `mibs :` in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` and installed the `snmp-mibs-downloader` package, now it works fine :)